# Decomposition of the difference of cubes

Tags: polynomials, fractions

I have to study the existence condition of the following algebraic fraction:
$$p=\frac{1}{a^3-b^3}$$
Since I can decompose the difference of the cube of $a$ and $b$ in this way: $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$, I can rewrite $p$ as:
$$p=\frac{1}{(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)}$$
So the existence conditions will correspond to the denominator different from $0$ and so:
$\begin{cases} a\neq b\\ a^2+ab+b^2\neq 0
\end{cases}$

I have a doubt: my Professor says that the terms "$a^2+ab+b^2$" is what we can call with "false square" and it is always $>0$.
But I think it is $\geq 0$, since if $a=b=0$ then it is null. I have found out that the false square is always $\neq 0$ also on the web, so I can't understand why. Can you hlep me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^2+ab+b^2=\Big(a+\frac{b}{2}\Big)^2+\frac{3b^2}{4}$ and the sum of two squares is always positive, unless $a=b=0$.

Comment: So as existence conditions I should write: $\color{red}{a\neq -b}$ and $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$? Or maybe the last two conditions are not necessary, since it is impossible that both $a$ and $b$ are null if I must have $\color{red}{a\neq -b}$?

Comment: The last one. It is enough to write $a\neq b$ because $a-b\neq 0$ and $a^2+ab+b^2>0$

Comment: Ok thanks! So maybe my professor considers that the "false square" is positive under the condition $a\neq -b$!